# TForm property that's an array (or collection) of TFrame descendants

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I am exploring [this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548567/array-property-tlist-tstringlist-or-tcollection-etc-delphi-win32) again, from a slightly different angle than before:

I have TForm descendant which is used in a couple of other components as a dialog, that I'd like to add as a property an array of counted TFrame descendants.

What multi-item property approach should I use for this? (Array, TList, TObjectList, TCollection, TOwnedCollection, etc).

(I'd also love to know, conceptually, "why")

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to base this on a TCollection.

Write a TCollectionItem descendant wrapper around your TFrame.

Make sure that when the TFrame instance is freed by someone else, that your TCollectionItem gets notified!

Use a [construction like mentioned here](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=90514) and [here](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=17085) for that.

--jeroen